# Django Celery jobs disappear for an hour before execution

Tags: celery, django-celery, celerybeat

We have this Django application that sends mail notifications about status change events, mainly as a paper trail.
The mail sending jobs are asynchronous, to not spoil the interactivity of the web application. We use celery tasks for that.

Since last week, some jobs have started to be discarded silently. They remain in the queue (visible with inspect reserved ) until the next celery workers restart which occurs every 10 minutes. Then they are gone but not performed.

Then **exactly** 1 hour later, mail is sent. Not at a 10 minutes slot start, but exactly 1 hour after original posting.

Sometimes I can even get 3 jobs scheduled by operator action within a few seconds, and one of them, potentially the middle one, will disappear for 1 hour.

Examples from same batch. the former is sent immediately, the latter afer an hour:

```
Generated at 24th mars 2021 06:55:44, for address user@gmail.com
Sent from Airtribune.com on 24th March 2021 06:55:45
```

```
Generated at 24th mars 2021 06:55:49, for address user@gmail.com
Sent from .com on 24th March 2021 07:57:13
```

The questions are:

- Where is the job visible ?
- Why does this happen ?
- Is there a way to force processing in more reasonable time ?

Thanks in advance